# Why can't I throw an exception from a method

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, block, throw

I am new at Java and am experiencing a bit of a problem with throwing exceptions. Namely, why is this incorrect

```
public static void divide(double x, double y) {
    if (y == 0){
        throw new Exception("Cannot divide by zero."); 
        // Generates error message that states the exception type is unhanded 
    }
    else
        System.out.println(x + " divided by " + y + " is " + x/y);
        // other code follows
}
```

But this OK?

```
public static void divide(double x, double y) {
    if (y == 0)
        throw new ArithmeticException("Cannot divide by zero.");
    else
        System.out.println(x + " divided by " + y + " is " + x/y);
        // other code follows
}
```

Comment: Blame a guy named Goodenough, ca 1974.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An [`ArithmeticException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) is a `RuntimeException`, so it doesn't need to be declared in a `throws` clause or caught by a `catch` block.  But `Exception` isn't a `RuntimeException`.

[Section 11.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2) covers this:

> The unchecked exception classes (§11.1.1) are exempted from compile-time checking.

The "unchecked exception classes" include `Error`s and `RuntimeException`s.

Additionally, you'll want to check if `y` is `0`, not if `x / y` is `0`.

Comment: I would like to generate a NotSerializableException when an object is being set up for Serialization - by checking `if(someObj instanceof Serializable)` That is not possible then?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a `throws` in the method signature **only** for checked exceptions. For example:

```
public static void divide(double x, double y) throws Exception {
 ...
}
```

Since [ArithmeticException extends RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html), there's no need of a `throws` in the second example.

More info:

- [Unchecked Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)

Answer (score 0):

Methods that throw exceptions in Java must delcare it in the method signature

`public static void divide(double x, double y) throws Exception`

Without the declaration your code will not compile.

There is a special subset of exceptions that extend the `RuntimeException` class. These exceptions do not need to be declared in the method signature.

`ArithmeticException` extends a `RuntimeException`

Answer (score 0):

[`ArithmeticException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) is an unchecked exception, since it extends [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/RuntimeException.html).  [`Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Exception.html), by contrast, is an checked exception type, as it does not extend either `RuntimeException` or [`Error`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Error.html).

Checked exceptions must be declared in the throws clause of the method signature of any method that can throw them.  Unchecked exceptions do not.

Using your example, adding `throws Exception` will be enough to get the method to compile.  Note though that any calling code would then need to handle the exception, either by catching it or declaring it as being thrown.

```java
public static void divide(double x, double y) throws Exception {
    if (y == 0){
        throw new Exception("Cannot divide by zero."); 
        // Generates error message that states the exception type is unhanded 
    }
    else
        System.out.println(x + " divided by " + y + " is " + x/y);
        // other code follows
}
```

This is documented in the [Java Language Specification (JLS)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-11.html):

> ### 11.1.1. The Kinds of Exceptions
>
> […]
>
> The *unchecked exception classes* are the run-time exception classes and the error classes.
>
> The *checked exception classes* are all exception classes other than the unchecked exception classes. That is, the checked exception classes are `Throwable` and all its subclasses other than `RuntimeException` and its subclasses and `Error` and its subclasses.
>
> […]
>
> ## 11.2. Compile-Time Checking of Exceptions
>
> The Java programming language requires that a program contains handlers for *checked exceptions* which can result from execution of a method or constructor ([§8.4.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.6), [§8.8.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.5)). This compile-time checking for the presence of exception handlers is designed to reduce the number of exceptions which are not properly handled. For each checked exception which is a possible result, the `throws` clause for the method or constructor must mention the class of that exception or one of the superclasses of the class of that exception ([§11.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3)).
>
> […]
> The unchecked exception classes ([§11.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1)) are exempted from compile-time checking.